# Unshift array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have an array of objects (this array comes as a prop from the parent component) and the object.
I have to add the object at the begging of my array.
I've tried different things - nothing works.

```
const array = [
    {
        key1: 'a',
        key2: 'b',
        key3: 'c',
    },
    {
        key1: 'd',
        key2: 'e',
        key3: 'f',
    },
];

const myObj = {
    key1: '1',
    key2: '2',
    key3: '3',
};
```

The result I want to see:

```
const myArray = [
    {
        key1: '1',
        key2: '2',
        key3: '3',
    },
    {
        key1: 'a',
        key2: 'b',
        key3: 'c',
    },
    {
        key1: 'd',
        key2: 'e',
        key3: 'f',
    },
];
```

Comment: `I've tried different things - nothing works.` What have you tried? `array.unshift(myObj)` works for me.

Comment: unshift doesn't create a new array, but modifies the main one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `spread` operator

```
const newArr = [newObj, ...array]
```

or

```
array.unshift(newObj)
```

Comment: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: Try to destructure like this , const component = ({ array }) => {                            
             const newArr = [newObj, ...array]       }